# Matching 8 girls to 8 boys

Tags: algorithm

Suppose there are 8 girls and 8 boys. Each person gives you a ranking of the 8 partners they could date in the order of their preference. For example, the first girl might give you [3, 6, 2, 8, 1, 4, 5, 7]; this means they like boy number 3 the best, then 6, and so on. If we match her with boy number 6, she won’t be that upset. In particular, let’s add a penalty of 1 for this pairing. Similarly, if boy number 6 had her as a third choice, we add 2 to the overall penalty as well.

Our objective is to design an *efficient* algorithm that pairs these boys and girls such that the overall penalty is minimized. This penalty is the sum of all 16 penalties, which is the distance of their match from their best choice.

I thought of this problem at 3 in morning, and it kept me from going back to bed. The naive solution takes O(n!) and that’s clearly unacceptable. I thought maybe I can make a graph representation and search the graph, but that might also require n! space. Divide and conquer didn’t come in handy, and any greedy algorithm didn’t seem to be optimal. Maybe linear programming can help, but I haven’t looked further into it.

Thanks for any guidance or suggestions.

Comment: Stable marriage [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem)?

Comment: help with your homework?

Comment: @ewcz wow, I didn’t know this was a known problem. Though in their version they are looking for a stable solution, and one might not exist. I am looking for most optimal.

Comment: @RuiLima it’s not homework. I am too old for that. It’s a problem that I came up with myself.

Comment: @darksky if I am not mistaken, the Gale-Shapley algorithm proved that the stable solution always exists provided one has equal number of women/men...

Comment: This is the assignment problem, with the cost of each pairing equal to the sum of the penalties from each member: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Comment: @MattTimmermans that’s awesome! It seems all of this is just well known. Thanks for sharing this link.

Comment: So it seems it was linear programming afterall.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the stable marriage problem, which can definitely be solved in better than O(N!) time. To solve this problem, you choose either the men or women (we will say men for this explanation) and iterate over all of the men who do not have a partner. You then look at that man's preference list and "propose" to the highest ranked woman on that list that this man has not proposed to. If the woman is unpaired or prefers this man to her current man, she will accept; otherwise, the man stays single. You continue iterating across all of the men until there no one is left unpaired.

This algorithm runs in O(N^2) time because there will never be more than N^2 proposals. This is because each man can propose to each woman, and there are N men and N women, so there are a total of N^2 unique proposals, and each proposal will only be done once, since the algorithm does not let a man propose to the same woman multiple times.

The solution produced by this algorithm is a stable solution, meaning that there is no pair of a man and a woman who would rather have each other than their current partners, and it is optimized for the gender that you iterate over (the men in my explanation, but you could just as easily run it over the women).

There are also algorithms that attempt to find a stable pairing that does not optimize for men or women but looks for a solution that works for everyone. For one such algorithm, you can start by finding the optimal marriages for both males and females (if they are the same, you know that is your answer without running through the algorithm), then look at the woman, w who is the person left worst off by the male optimized pairing, and her partner m, in the male optimized matching. Perform another male optimized matching, except this time, start with m proposing to the woman w who is next on his preference list. If the person left worst off in this next pairing is a man, your answer is the previous pairing, else, continue performing additional male optimized pairings with the same change to the worst off person in this pairing until you find a pairing where the worst off person is a man and you have your answer (the last pairing before a man was worst off). This algorithm will minimize the max distance between people's preferred partner and their actual partner. This algorithm would be in O(N^4), since it finds a stable matching no more than N^2 times.